# Managing a memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using an zip/unzip library that seems to have a pretty bad memory leak.

I know it's a memory leak somewhere withing the library because I have managed to remove the leak by commenting just a method call of the library.

While the library isn't that big, it's written in C and is very compact with a bunch of macros and I don't want to spend a week figuring out how it works in order to patch the leak.

Fortunately for me, I use the library only within a single method. Is it possible to encase the code that engages the library in a block of sorts which will tell the compiler to track any heap allocations within this block and then to release all of them after the block is exited? Similar to how it manages stack memory. It might not be the perfect solution, but for my needs it would be more than good enough.

This might be unsafe otherwise, but in this case, if I allocate any memory I need prior to the block, I shouldn't have any problems since the library is initialized, used and uninitialized in a few lines, and I provide it with pointers to data to unzip, as well as pointer to already allocated memory where it can store the unzipped data.

Other than that, do you know any other c++ libraries that can deal with zip files created with C# SharpZipLib, the required condition being able to zip and unzip directly from a memory stream into another memory stream?

Comment: Pro-tip: if you spot a memory leak in a library, report it to the authors and stay away from it until it is fixed

Comment: The [Boehm garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't know about blocks, but you could compile the library with `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, `free` re`#define`d to do whatever you want. Implementing the "track and release together" approach you're describing isn't too hard, then.

Comment: Right... Okay, I didn't think of that. I'll either try to implement the mentioned Boehm GC, or write my own solution that would just keep a list of allocations that would get removed if freed and then force-free when the library is done. If you can type it as an answer, I'll tick it as solved.

Comment: Rhetorical. Who cares about leaks anymore? Or is it that bad that it is going to overrun swap?

Comment: @SergeyA Any leak can overrun swap. That's what a leak is.

Comment: @melpomene, theoretically yes. Does it practically happen, though?

Comment: How do you know that there is a leak? How do you know that you aren’t leaking?

Comment: By not being an idiot. I ran the program through the same scenario with the line commented and uncommented. I isloated it in a single block and paused the execution of the program a single line before the end. Without the line - 17MB allocated (I might have another leak in another library, yay); with the line - 100MB. Yeah, the library is leaking.

Comment: I ran the program again and multiplied the times the method that causes the problem by a 1000. It gobbled up over 8 GB of memory before I killed it. A program that needs 20MB at most in a single moment. If that isn't a memory leak, then what is?

Comment: Since it seems easily reproducable, it shouldn't take a week to fit the leak (if you have the source).

Comment: What platform?  The Microsoft library has some useful tools for diagnosing memory leaks.  For Linux, take a look at valgrind (and friends)

Comment: I'm using VS2017. It's profiler is how I noticed this.

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.90).aspx) describes how to enable the Microsoft DEBUG heap which will provide a lot of information about memory leaks -- including letting you set a breakpoint on the allocation that will eventually leak (assuming your program behavior is deterministic/consistent).

Turn it on this way:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
```

and get a detailed report by adding a call to:

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```